# MultiTrigger not working properly in .Net MAUI

Tags: maui

I have tried to use the MultiTrigger with MultiValue Binding using the Label control but it does not work.

```xml
<HorizontalStackLayout>
    <Label Text="Inspection Score: "
            IsVisible="true"
            Style="{StaticResource CardTitleLabelStyle}"/>
    <Label
        HorizontalOptions="Start"
        VerticalOptions="Center"
        Style="{StaticResource CardTitleLabelStyle}">
        <Label.Text>
            <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} | {1}">
                <Binding Path="ViolationScore" />
                <Binding Path="ViolationRating" />
            </MultiBinding>
        </Label.Text>
        <Label.Triggers>
            <MultiTrigger TargetType="Label">
                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Path=ViolationRating}" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <BindingCondition Binding="{Binding Path=ViolationRating}" Value="" />
                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Text"
                        Value="{Binding Path=ViolationScore}" />
            </MultiTrigger>
        </Label.Triggers>
    </Label>
</HorizontalStackLayout>
```

According to this code, it should display Only Score if the Rating is null. But though the value of the **ViolationRating** is null it shows below output:

```
Inspection Score: 95 |
```

Which is wrong, anyone know how to handle this?

Comment: Can you give a little more context? What exactly are you trying to achieve? From your description and code it's not entirely clear which scenarios are possible and what you're expecting to see in each case. Also, using a setter in a trigger that changes the `Text` property will overwrite the `MultiBinding` of the same property. You may need to approach this differently, but for that more context would be helpful.

Comment: Basically, I have a property called ViolationRating. I want to show the PIPE and ViolationRating values only if its not null or empty. That I'm trying to achieve using this trigger. I have got the solution though using IMultiValueConverter.

Comment: Why are you not using a basic converter for this, It looks like an overkill to use multi binding for just hiding a label if its empty, if that's what you want i can add a basic example

Comment: Its not just about hiding a label. If you check my sample code I have used MultiBiding with formate. So, I have to use MultiValueConvert to format the text and control the visibility at same time.

Comment: All the transformation logic can be implemented all in ViewModel, so you may not need to use multibinding or multitrigger. Anyway, so glad you solved it!